# scope function inside controller not updating the values according to ng-models in the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i got this function in the controller that is called from the ng-view:

```
productApp.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, productFactory, prodId) {     

$scope.ok = function () {
          console.log($scope.model_productDescription);
          $scope.$watch(['model_productBrand,model_productName,model_productDescription,model_productPrice, model_productStock'], function() {
              var stock = '';
              if($scope.model_productStock) {
                  stock = 'AVAILABLE';
              }else{
                  stock = 'NO STOCK';
              }

              var productObject = {
                      id : prodId,
                      prodBrand : $scope.model_productBrand,
                      prodName : $scope.model_productName,
                      description : $scope.model_productDescription,
                      price : $scope.model_productPrice,
                      prodStock : stock
              }

              productFactory.updateProductById(productObject, function successCallback(data) {
                  // do something here in data
              }, function errorCallback(data, status) {
                  alert(data + ' Failed with error ' + status); 
              }); 
          })     
      };
});
```

This is the modal.htm body:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="cancel()">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modify a Product</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <fieldset>          
                <!-- Row 1 -->
                <div class="col-md-12 col-centered">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="prod_brand">Product Brand</label>
                        <input type="text" id="prod_brand" class="form-control"
                            ng-model="model_productBrand" required="required" value="prod.prodBrand">
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="prod_name">Product Type</label> <input
                            type="text" id="prod_name" class="form-control"
                            ng-model="model_productName" required="required" value="prod.prodName">
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="prod_price">Price</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span> <input type="text"
                                class="form-control" ng-model="model_productPrice" value="prod.price"> <span
                                class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="prod_description">Description</label>
                        <textarea id="prod_description" class="form-control" ng-model="model_productDescription" cols="70" rows="3">{{prod.description}}</textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group" style="margin-top: 10px">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="model_productStock">
                            </span> 
                            <span class="form-control no-cursor">Stock</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">Edit product</button>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Now, if i type in the textarea (for example), and press the ok button, it will get into this function. Now, since the textarea value has changed, shouldn't be reflected in the $scope.productDescription value? looks like it's not. I thought that whenever you make a change in the model, it would override the $scope.model_name value, should i use ng-change or any other directive for this?

Tried adding a $watch but it's not working either, any suggestion?

P.S: console.log($scope.model_productDescription); // shows the old description despite the fact i change it

Thanks.

Comment: Add the html sections where you bind the the model. Also where is the controller with method `ok` declared.

Comment: @Chandermani done, updated it with the info :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most probable cause of this is that your model.html is creating child scope. The changes that you do to the model property are local to child and cannot be seen in the parent due to prototypal inheritance.

What you can try is to create an object on the controller and do binding on object property.

`$scope.productObject={};`

Do the textarea binding to

```
 <textarea id="prod_description" class="form-control" ng-model="productObject.productDescription" cols="70" rows="3">{{prod.description}}</textarea>
```

Now the changes would be reflected in `productObject.productDescription` property.

Also go through this wiki to understand how does scope inheritance works https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: Happens that the ng-model="model_productDescription" was used before to fill the description attribute from the existent product in the database. If i change the binding to that, it would conflict on the other one.

Comment: omg as you said, creates a childScope i can see the changes when accessing to the "childTail", then if i do another change on the form and click ok, it creates another childTail inside the other childTail containing the new changes and so on D: it's a god damn loop of childTails :'(

Comment: The bottom line is you need to use `.` based model expression or object property binding instead of directly binding to the property on $scope.

Answer (score 0):

God... i'm going to fix it as of now by doing this:

From the view:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok(model_productBrand, model_productName, model_productPrice, model_productDescription, model_productStock)">Edit product</button>
```

From the controller passing the vars to the ok() function:

```
$scope.ok = function (model_productBrand, model_productName, model_productDescription, model_productPrice, model_productStock) {
```

Yeah... i know it looks UGLY as hell, but bleh...

Thank you, anyway i'm going to tick your answer as correct since the solution you gave me is really convenient, the only problem was that my project was kinda bad design for the solution you provided :P but is good!